# Golang (beginner): Avoiding duplicate functions to deal with strings or ints

Tags: go

I've started learning Go today, so this may be a silly question. I'm used to PHP whereby I don't have to declare variable types.

I'm currently converting some of my commonly used PHP functions into Go functions. I have a function which converts an array into a hashtable for fast lookups later on (much faster than iterating through the array to see if a value exists, instead the values become keys.)

It seems to me that I have to create two separate functions, one for strings and one for integers (`uint` as I don't need signed integers). For the sake of maintenance I would prefer to have one function that can accept either `string` or `uint` and return the same, i.e. it works in and returns whatever I originally pass to the function.

Currently I have this:

```
//  Array2Map_string makes a map out of an array of strings: word=>false
func Array2Map_string(a []string) map[string]bool {
    mc := make(map[string]bool)
    for _,tok := range a {
         mc[tok]=false
        }
    return mc
}

//  Array2Map_int makes a map out of an array of integers: int=>false
func Array2Map_int(a []uint) map[uint]bool {
    mc := make(map[uint]bool)
    for _,tok := range a {
         mc[tok]=false
        }
    return mc
}
```

What I would like is to have a single function that will create and return a string based hashtable if I send a string array to the function, or a uint based hashtable if I send a uint array to the function. Example:

```
//  Array2Map makes a map out of an array of strings whereby the key is
func Array2Map(a []whatever) map[whatever]bool {
    mc := make(map[whatever]bool)
    for _,tok := range a {
         mc[tok]=false
        }
    return mc
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Short answer: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions - and call it SliceToMap, because []uint or []string is a slice in Go. Your function will accept an interface{}, type assert it, create a new map and range over the old one to copy each value into the new one, before returning the new map as an interface{}. The caller will need to type assert the map before checking the keys.

Comment: That seems like it might be more complicated than just using two separate functions.

Comment: Check out the [gen](http://clipperhouse.github.io/gen/) project for ideas to make this less painful, if you need more than just two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics don't exist in Go yet (although there is a lot of [discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1x7txi/why_generics/) about it. For now, I think your current direction is your only option.